# Why my data doesn't get displayed on the Screen after saving it in other screen in android jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-room

I have a screen named **ScreenPlay** where there are Cards with an option to save them. After i check them in Logcat; it does show that the data has been saved. But when I navigate to the screen **ScreenLearn** nothing really . The screen is empty. Below is my code.

ScreenPlay.kt

```
@Composable
fun ScreenPlay(navController: NavController){

    // Mutable state to hold the dynamically updated saved cards
    var savedCards by remember { mutableStateOf(emptyList<SavedCard>()) }

    lateinit var playList:List<ImageModel>
    playList = ArrayList()
    playList = listOf(
        ImageModel("Tejas",R.drawable.television,R.drawable.save),
                   ImageModel("Nikita",R.drawable.food,R.drawable.save),
                   ImageModel("xyz",R.drawable.dish,R.drawable.save),
                   ImageModel("gggg",R.drawable.bird,R.drawable.save)
    )
    val context = LocalContext.current

    val cardViewmodel: ScreenViewModel = viewModel(
        factory = ScreenViewmodelFactory((context.applicationContext as MyApp).repository)
    )


  //  val navController = rememberNavController()
//For using the object on ArrowBack Icon
    val onBackPressedDispatcher = LocalOnBackPressedDispatcherOwner.current?.onBackPressedDispatcher
    Scaffold(topBar = {
        TopAppBar(title = { Text(text = "Days") },
            navigationIcon = {
                IconButton(onClick = { navController.popBackStack() }) {

                    Icon(
                        Icons.Default.ArrowBack,
                        contentDescription = "Back",
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(16.dp)
                            .clickable { onBackPressedDispatcher?.onBackPressed() }
                    )

                }
            }

        )
    },
        floatingActionButton = {
            FloatingActionButton(onClick = {
                      navController.navigate(Destinations.ScreenLearn)
            },
                modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 50.dp, end = 40.dp)
            ) {
                Icon(
                    Icons.Default.Add,
                    contentDescription = "Save"
                )
            }
        },
        floatingActionButtonPosition = FabPosition.End
    ) {
        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(10.dp)
                .padding(bottom = 56.dp)
                .navigationBarsPadding()
        ) {
            items(playList.size) {
                Card(
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(20.dp),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(8.dp)
                        .height(150.dp),
                    elevation = 6.dp,
                ) {
                    Box{
                        Column(
                            Modifier
                                .fillMaxSize()
                                .padding(5.dp)
                                .background(Color(153, 50, 204))
                                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(20.dp)),
                            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                        ) {
                            Image(
                                painter = painterResource(id = playList[it].imageId),
                                contentDescription = "Images"
                            )

                            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 5.dp))
                            Text(
                                text = playList[it].imageName,
                                color = Color.White,
                                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
                            )

                        }
                        Image(painter = painterResource(id = playList[it].imageSaved), contentDescription = "Save data",
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(8.dp)
                                .padding(top = 10.dp)
                                .align(Alignment.TopEnd)
                                .clickable {

                                    val imagename = playList[it].imageName
                                    val imageResource = playList[it].imageId

                                    val newSaved =
                                        SavedCard(imageId =imageResource, imageName = imagename)
                                    savedCards += newSaved
                                    cardViewmodel.insertCards(newSaved)
                                    Log.d("Database", "Value saved: $newSaved")
                                    Toast.makeText(context,"Image saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()


                                }
                        )
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    }
```

ScreenLearn.kt

```
@SuppressLint("UnusedMaterialScaffoldPaddingParameter")
@Composable
fun ScreenLearn(savedCards: List<SavedCard>) {

    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(title = { Text(text = "Screen Learn") })
        }
    ) {
        LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)) {
            items(savedCards) { savedCard ->
                Card(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(bottom = 16.dp),
                    elevation = 4.dp,
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)
                ) {
                    Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)) {
                        Text(text = savedCard.imageName, style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6)
                        Image(
                            painter = painterResource(id = savedCard.imageId),
                            contentDescription = savedCard.imageName,

                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .padding(top = 8.dp)
                                .height(200.dp)
                                .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                                .background(Color.LightGray)
                        )

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also have viewModel class as ScreenViewModel

ScreenViewModel.kt

```
class ScreenViewModel(private val savedCardRepository:SavedCardRepository):ViewModel() {


    // Using LiveData and caching what allWords returns has several benefits:
    // - We can put an observer on the data (instead of polling for changes) and only update the
    //   the UI when the data actually changes.
    // - Repository is completely separated from the UI through the ViewModel.
    var allWords: LiveData<List<SavedCard>> = savedCardRepository.savedCards.asLiveData()

    /**
     * Launching a new coroutine to insert the data in a non-blocking way
     */
    fun insertCards(savedCard: SavedCard) = viewModelScope.launch {
        savedCardRepository.saveCard(savedCard)
    }

    fun deleteCards(savedCard: SavedCard) = viewModelScope.launch {
        savedCardRepository.deleteCard(savedCard)
    }

}

class ScreenViewmodelFactory(private val savedCardRepository:SavedCardRepository) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(ScreenViewModel::class.java)) {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return ScreenViewModel(savedCardRepository) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
    }
}
```

I am also adding the navigation setup code below [App.kt]

```
@Composable
fun App() {


    val navController = rememberNavController()
    val items = listOf<String>("User","Play")
    val selectedItem = remember {
        mutableStateOf(0)
    }
    val savedCards = remember { mutableStateListOf<SavedCard>() }

    Scaffold(bottomBar = {
        BottomNavigation {
            items.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
                BottomNavigationItem(selected = selectedItem.value == index,
                    onClick = {
                        selectedItem.value = index
                        when(index){
                            0->navController.navigate(Destinations.ScreenA)
                            1->navController.navigate(Destinations.ScreenPlay)
                        }
                              },
                    icon = {
                        if (index==0){
                            Icon(Icons.Default.Person, contentDescription = item)

                        }else{
                            Icon(Icons.Default.PlayArrow, contentDescription = item)
                        }
                         },
                    label = { Text(text = item) }
                )

            }

        }
    }
    ) {
        NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = Destinations.ScreenA) {

            composable(ScreenA) {
                ScreenA(navController)
            }
            composable(ScreenB) {
                ScreenB(navController)
            }
            composable(ScreenC) {
                ScreenC(navController)
            }

            composable(Destinations.ScreenPlay){
                ScreenPlay(navController)
            }
            composable(Destinations.ScreenLearn){

                ScreenLearn(savedCards = savedCards)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't quite understand where am I wrong with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You are updating only the database in this function.

```
  fun insertCards(savedCard: SavedCard) = viewModelScope.launch {
        savedCardRepository.saveCard(savedCard)
    }
```

But LiveData inside the ViewModel is not updated , it will be updated once the viewModel is destroyed and created again so it fetches again from the repository.

Also update your liveData

```
   private val _allWords: LiveData<List<SavedCard>> = savedCardRepository.savedCards.asLiveData()
        
//edit
     val allWords = MutableLiveData<List<SavedCard>>(_allWords.value)



    /**
     * Launching a new coroutine to insert the data in a non-blocking way
     */
    fun insertCards(savedCard: SavedCard) = viewModelScope.launch {
        savedCardRepository.saveCard(savedCard)
        allWords.value?.add(savedCard)
        allWords.value = allWords.value
    }
```

Observe LiveData from the viewModel and pass into ScreenLearn composable.

```
val list by viewModel.allCards.observeAsState()
ScreenLearn(savedCards = list )
```

To use observeAsState() you need to add this dependency

```
dependencies {
      ...
      implementation("androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.4.2")
}
```

You have to make sure that you are passing in the same instance of ViewModel to both of your screens thus making it a shared ViewModel.

Watch the SharedViewModel part of this [video](https://youtu.be/h61Wqy3qcKg).

**EDIT**

Don't intialize the viewModel inside your composable instead do it
in your NavHost and pass into the screens as paramter.

```
  val cardViewmodel: ScreenViewModel = viewModel(
        factory = ScreenViewmodelFactory((context.applicationContext as MyApp).repository)
    )
 NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = Destinations.ScreenA) {

    
  
            composable(ScreenA) {
                ScreenA(navController)
            }
            composable(ScreenB) {
                ScreenB(navController)
            }
            composable(ScreenC) {
                ScreenC(navController)
            }

            composable(Destinations.ScreenPlay){
                ScreenPlay(navController,viewModel)
            }
            composable(Destinations.ScreenLearn){
            //edit
 val savedCards by cardViewModel.allCards.observeAsState()
            
               ScreenLearn(savedCards = savedCards)
            }
        }
```

Comment: savedCardRepository.savedCards.asLiveData() and     allWords.value?.add(savedCard) [add in this code] are giving errors

Comment: I have added an extra file that shows the  navigation setup. Could you check it and give me updated code at the areas that you are saying to write the code? Sorry, I am new to Jetpack compose so bit confused and vexed.

Comment: I have edit my answer , can you also paste in the error

Comment: Nope , it's giving new errors. It's saying "@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function" . This error occurs when i created instance of ScreenViewModel in NavHost.

Comment: var allWords: MutableLiveData<List<SavedCard>> = savedCardRepository.savedCards.asLiveData()
 This code gives following error "Required:
MutableLiveData<List<SavedCard>>,Found:
LiveData<List<SavedCard>>"

Comment: @PurpleRabbit sorry for the confusion, move view model initialization out of the NavHost, and I have edit the LiveData code too.

Comment: val allWords = MutableLiveData<List<SavedCard>>(allWords.value) 'allWords.value" is showing error and also allWords.value?.add(savedCard) "add is showing error" ... and also val savedCards by viewModel.allCards.observeAsState() "viewModel" shows error

Comment: These all are due to silly mistake 1) val allWords = MutableLiveData<List<SavedCard>>(_allWords.value)  Add the underscore before _allWords.value 2) the viewModel is initialised as cardViewModel and then we are retrieving using viewModel so just change it to cardViewModel.allWords.observerAsState()

Comment: Can you make changes in the above code and put comments? so I can just copy paste

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254188/discussion-between-purplerabbit-and-zaid-khan).